# The box-shadow property after comma

Tags: css

In button **Post Your Question** i found this `css`

```
box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) inset;
```

I was thinkins there is just one part in property `box-shadow` so what mean the second `,0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) inset` ?

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

Comment: Google is your friend.

Comment: there is nothing there about my question @j08691

Comment: "The box-shadow CSS property describes **one or more shadow effects as a comma-separated list**."

Comment: Yes man i don't speak english very well ;)

Comment: @j08691 English is not everyone's first language. The question shows curiosity, work invested, and learning by example... pulling from SO's own code no less.

Comment: @digitalextremist - there's a difference between not being a native English speaker and not doing the simplest of research.

Comment: @j08691 ... the word `inset` is not self-explanatory. Knowing the language is the key to knowing what to search for. I very rarely see new users go through SO's own code for pointers! He's trying hard. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the shadow ***inside*** the box. The first part is the shadow *around* the box.

---

Here is a good article for you:

- http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/

Look for *Inner Shadow* in the article.